# How can I improve the performance of my query when using count in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

For some reason, when adding AND US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez ', the query slows down and does not generate result. However, if I carry out the internal query (the one that uses the FROM) it does bring me what I need, but when implementing the COUNT(*) it doesn't, what can I do to improve the performance of SQL?

```
SELECT MEDIO, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
INNER JOIN TBLCATALU TB ON C.IDECATALU = TB.IDECATALU
INNER JOIN (SELECT AC.NOMASE||' '||AC.PATASE||' '||AC.MATASE AS ASESOR, AC.USUAPE, USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE AS USERAPEX 
            FROM TBLASECRM AC
            INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID ) US ON C.USUINSREG = US.USERAPEX
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AC2.NOMASE||' '||AC2.PATASE||' '||AC2.MATASE AS ASESOR2, AC2.USUAPE AS USUAPE_MOD
            FROM TBLASECRM AC2
            INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID) US2 ON C.USUMODREG = US2.USUAPE_MOD
WHERE C.STATUS = 'A'
    AND (--(:P483_FECHA_FIN IS NULL AND :P483_FECHA_INICIO IS NULL)
         --OR 
         (TO_DATE(C.FECINSREG,'DD/MM/YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/23','DD/MM/YY')   AND  TO_DATE('23/06/23','DD/MM/YY')) )
   AND('DANIEL.C' IN ('DANIEL.C','BRENDA','MARIO') OR( (C.USUMODREG IN (SELECT AC.USUAPE FROM TBLASECRM AC
                                INNER JOIN TBLASECRM AC2 ON AC.SUPASE_ID = AC2.PKIDASE AND ac2.DESPUE = 'Supervisor'
                                INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                                WHERE US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                       union 
                                select USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID from USUARIOS_SISTEMA where USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C') 
        OR C.USUINSREG IN ( SELECT  USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE FROM USUARIOS_SISTEMA WHERE USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID IN (
                            SELECT AC.USUAPE FROM TBLASECRM AC
                                INNER JOIN TBLASECRM AC2 ON AC.SUPASE_ID = AC2.PKIDASE AND ac2.DESPUE = 'Supervisor'
                                INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                                WHERE US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C')
                         union 
                                select USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE from USUARIOS_SISTEMA where USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C')   )
    OR
        ( C.USUMODREG = (SELECT US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID FROM TBLASECRM AC
                        INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                           WHERE AC.DESPUE = 'Asesor Académico'
                           AND US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C') 
        OR C.USUINSREG = (SELECT US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE FROM TBLASECRM AC
                        INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                           WHERE AC.DESPUE = 'Asesor Académico'
                           AND US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C') )
      )) AND US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
        
                                     ) --WHERE ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
      GROUP BY MEDIO;
```

Comment: where is your EXPLAIN PLAN?

Comment: `SELECT *`  should only have column that you need, eslse you have a load of baggage that isn't usefull, besides it is a bad habit, that you should get rid of

Comment: Your inner query returns you a first N rows (generally 50-100 depending on the IDE), but `count(*)` forces it to process all the input and return only then

Comment: Did you try `AND US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez'`? Currently you have a trailing blank... If so, what's the output of `SELECT AC.nomase || ' ' || AC.patase || ' ' || AC.matase AS ASESOR, AC.usuape, usuario_sistema_clave AS USERAPEX FROM tblasecrm AC inner join usuarios_sistema US ON AC.usuape = US.usuario_sistema_id AND AC.nomase || ' ' || AC.patase || ' ' || AC.matase = 'Olga Rodriguez '`?

Comment: This is the output: Olga Rodriguez  154 ASESOR65

@Abecee

The blank space is part of the record

Comment: If you change the **US** subquery this way - does the outmost subquery still return a non-empty result set?

Comment: @Abecee No matter how long I wait, it yields nothing.

Comment: You might want to verify the inner query to return anything at all. Drop initially the whole `WHERE` clause. Add back in one part at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`'DANIEL.C' IN ('DANIEL.C','BRENDA','MARIO')` will always be true and `true OR anything` is true so you can ignore the `anything` part of the query:

If you format your query neatly:

```sql
SELECT MEDIO,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
         INNER JOIN TBLCATALU TB
         ON C.IDECATALU = TB.IDECATALU
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT AC.NOMASE||' '||AC.PATASE||' '||AC.MATASE AS ASESOR,
                  AC.USUAPE,
                  USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE AS USERAPEX 
            FROM TBLASECRM AC
                 INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                 ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
          ) US
          ON C.USUINSREG = US.USERAPEX
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AC2.NOMASE||' '||AC2.PATASE||' '||AC2.MATASE AS ASESOR2,
                   AC2.USUAPE AS USUAPE_MOD
            FROM   TBLASECRM AC2
                   INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                   ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
          ) US2
          ON C.USUMODREG = US2.USUAPE_MOD
  WHERE   C.STATUS = 'A'
  AND     ( --(:P483_FECHA_FIN IS NULL AND :P483_FECHA_INICIO IS NULL)
            --OR 
            ( TO_DATE(C.FECINSREG,'DD/MM/YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/23','DD/MM/YY')
                                              AND     TO_DATE('23/06/23','DD/MM/YY')
            )
          )
  AND     (
            'DANIEL.C' IN ('DANIEL.C','BRENDA','MARIO')
            OR
            (
              (
                C.USUMODREG IN (
                  SELECT AC.USUAPE
                  FROM   TBLASECRM AC
                         INNER JOIN TBLASECRM AC2
                         ON   AC.SUPASE_ID = AC2.PKIDASE
                              AND ac2.DESPUE = 'Supervisor'
                         INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                         ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                  WHERE  US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                  union 
                  select USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                  from   USUARIOS_SISTEMA
                  where  USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                )
                OR C.USUINSREG IN (
                  SELECT USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE
                  FROM   USUARIOS_SISTEMA
                  WHERE  USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID IN (
                    SELECT AC.USUAPE
                    FROM   TBLASECRM AC
                           INNER JOIN TBLASECRM AC2
                           ON AC.SUPASE_ID = AC2.PKIDASE
                              AND ac2.DESPUE = 'Supervisor'
                           INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                           ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                    WHERE  US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                  )
                  union 
                  select USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE
                  from   USUARIOS_SISTEMA
                  where USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                )
              )
              OR
              (
                C.USUMODREG = (
                  SELECT US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                  FROM   TBLASECRM AC
                         INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                         ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                  WHERE  AC.DESPUE = 'Asesor Académico'
                  AND    US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                ) 
                OR C.USUINSREG = (
                  SELECT US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE
                  FROM   TBLASECRM AC
                         INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                         ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
                  WHERE  AC.DESPUE = 'Asesor Académico'
                         AND US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE= 'DANIEL.C'
                )
              )
            )
          )
  AND     US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
)
--WHERE ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
GROUP BY MEDIO;
```

Then you can see that you can remove over half of the query:

```sql
SELECT MEDIO,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
         INNER JOIN TBLCATALU TB
         ON C.IDECATALU = TB.IDECATALU
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT AC.NOMASE||' '||AC.PATASE||' '||AC.MATASE AS ASESOR,
                  AC.USUAPE,
                  USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE AS USERAPEX 
            FROM TBLASECRM AC
                 INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                 ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
          ) US
          ON C.USUINSREG = US.USERAPEX
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT AC2.NOMASE||' '||AC2.PATASE||' '||AC2.MATASE AS ASESOR2,
                   AC2.USUAPE AS USUAPE_MOD
            FROM   TBLASECRM AC2
                   INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                   ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
          ) US2
          ON C.USUMODREG = US2.USUAPE_MOD
  WHERE   C.STATUS = 'A'
  AND     TO_DATE(C.FECINSREG,'DD/MM/YY') BETWEEN DATE '2023-01-01'
                                          AND     DATE '2023-06-23'
  AND     US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
)
--WHERE ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
GROUP BY MEDIO;
```

and then further to:

```sql
SELECT MEDIO,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM   ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
       INNER JOIN TBLCATALU TB
       ON C.IDECATALU = TB.IDECATALU
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT AC.NOMASE||' '||AC.PATASE||' '||AC.MATASE AS ASESOR,
                AC.USUAPE,
                USUARIO_SISTEMA_CLAVE AS USERAPEX 
         FROM   TBLASECRM AC
                INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                ON AC.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
       ) US
       ON C.USUINSREG = US.USERAPEX
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT AC2.NOMASE||' '||AC2.PATASE||' '||AC2.MATASE AS ASESOR2,
                AC2.USUAPE AS USUAPE_MOD
         FROM   TBLASECRM AC2
                INNER JOIN USUARIOS_SISTEMA US
                ON AC2.USUAPE = US.USUARIO_SISTEMA_ID
       ) US2
       ON C.USUMODREG = US2.USUAPE_MOD
WHERE  C.STATUS = 'A'
AND    TO_DATE(C.FECINSREG,'DD/MM/YY') BETWEEN DATE '2023-01-01'
                                       AND     DATE '2023-06-23'
AND    US.ASESOR = 'Olga Rodriguez '
GROUP BY MEDIO;
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one column and count as total required as a output of query then all other query column formatting and * can be avoided.

Please try if below work

```
Select MEDIO , count(*)over(partition by MEDIO order by MEDIO) as Total from  ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
---all code
---------- instead 
SELECT MEDIO, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM (SELECT * FROM ALUMNOS_CONTACTADOS  C
----all code
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).